# Cypress unable to select multiselect with loop

Tags: javascript, cypress, grommet

I am writing a React application that I'm testing with Cypress. In my integration tests I've written a cypress command that takes an array of strings, in order to select items in a multi-value select box.

The code I'm using looks roughly like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("command", (options) => {
  options.forEach((option) => {
    cy.get("div[data-g-portal-id='1']") // this is the container for the select box dropdown
      .find("div[role='menubar']")
      .contains(option)
      .click({ force: true });
  });
}
```

I've tried various iterations of this, including things like `cy.wrap` and `.each`. Whatever I do, when the array contains more than one item, it clicks one item, the item is marked as selected successfully, then it clicks the other item, marks *it* as selected, but the first item loses its selection state. Its as if the internal state of the component never really got the initial change.

I've confirmed this is not a bug in my application; when testing it manually, the multi-select works fine. But Cypress just doesn't want to know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What React component are you using?

Comment: @MarionMorrison https://v2.grommet.io/select

Answer (score 0):

The v2.grommet.io/select uses a "portal" to display the dropdown options.

The portal is just a `div` that's appended to `body` when the dropdown opened and removed again when an option is clicked.

Problem is, there isn't a property to connect the dropdown and portal containing the options. There may be other portals present e.g the `Layer` component uses a portal.

The options portal we need to target will always be the last portal on the page (since we just opened the dropdown). In the custom command, applying the `.last()` command will select the options portal.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("multiselect", (options) => {
  options.forEach((option) => {

    cy.get(`[data-g-portal-id]`)
      .last()            // just opened the dropdown so option are in the last portal
      .find("div[role='menubar']")
      .contains(option)
      .click();
  });
});


cy.get('input[name="my-select"]')
  .click();                           // open dropdown
  .multiselect(['First', 'Third']);

cy.get('input[name="my-select"]')
  .click();                           // close dropdown

cy.get('input[name="my-select"]')
  .should('have.value', 'multiple')
```

The test ends with dropdown displaying the text "multiple".

---

Configuration of the Select,

```html
<Select
  multiple               // allow multiple selected options
  closeOnChange={false}  // do not close the dropdown between selections
  name="my-select"       
  options={myOptions}
  ...
/>
```